# CycleJs - Subscribing events of the same element which has different classes

Tags: cyclejs, virtual-dom

I created an element with class *foo*. Then I intended to swap its class with *bar* after an click event was occurred. However, when I clicked the element, streams that subscribes the click events of the *foo* and *bar* were triggered successively. As a result, element's class didn't change.
How can I subscribe events of the same element where its classes change in time?

Here's the link:

https://jsbin.com/kanomonexa/edit?html,js,console,output

Here's the sample code:

```js
const {div, button, makeDOMDriver} = CycleDOM;
const toggleDriver = (data$)=> {
    data$.subscribe(function(data) {
        if (data.operation === 'remove' ) {
            $(data.selector).removeClass(data.className);
        }
        else if (data.operation === 'add') {
            $(data.selector).addClass(data.className);
        }
        else {
            $(data.selector).toggle(data.className);
        }

    });

    return Rx.Observable.empty();
};

const consoleLogDriver = (data$)=>{
  data$.subscribe(data=> {
        console.log(data);
  });

  return Rx.Observable.empty();
};

const main = (sources) =>{
  const fooClick$ = sources.DOM
  .select('.foo')
  .events('click');
  const fooLog$ = fooClick$.map(_ =>'.foo is Clicked');
  const toggleFoo$ = fooClick$.flatMap(_ => {
    const result = [
      {
        operation: 'remove',
        selector: 'button',
        className: 'foo'
      },
      {
        operation: 'add',
        selector: 'button',
        className: 'bar'
      }
    ];
    return Rx.Observable.fromArray(result);
  });
  
  const barClick$ = sources.DOM
  .select('.bar')
  .events('click');
  const barLog$ = barClick$.map(_ => '.bar is Clicked');
  const toggleBar$ = barClick$.flatMap(_ =>{
    const result = [
      {
        operation: 'remove',
        selector: 'button',
        className: 'bar'
      },
      {
        operation: 'add',
        selector: 'button',
        className: 'foo'
      }
    ];
    return Rx.Observable.fromArray(result);
  });
  
  const log$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
    fooLog$,
    barLog$
  );
  const toggle$ = Rx.Observable.merge(
    toggleFoo$,
    toggleBar$
  );
  
  const vTree$ = Rx.Observable.of(div([
    button('#button.foo',['Click me'])
    
  ]));
  
  return {
    DOM: vTree$,
    consoleLogDriver: log$,
    toggleDriver:toggle$
  };
};

var drivers = {
  DOM: makeDOMDriver('#app'),
  toggleDriver: toggleDriver,
  consoleLogDriver: consoleLogDriver
};

Cycle.run(main, drivers);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.6/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cyclejs/cycle-core/v6.0.3/dist/cycle.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/cyclejs/cycle-dom/v9.4.0/dist/cycle-dom.js"></script>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `delay(0)` your toggle$ stream to schedule its values to the next event loop and then successfully change your className:

```js
...
const toggle$ = Observable.merge(...)
  .delay(0)
...
```

---

I see that you are using Jquery to toggle your class. Depending on what you want to do, I imagine it can have some usefull cases (eg: toggle a class somewhere else in the page out of scope from virtual dom).

But there your cycle app is handled by virtual dom so I suggest you to use the right tool for the job and instead rebuild your vtree$ on each change:

```js
...
const currentClassName$ = Rx.Observable
  .merge(
    fooClick$.map(_ => '.bar'),
    barClick$.map(_ => '.foo')
  )
  .delay(0) // fix the bug
  .startWith('.foo');

const vTree$ = currentClassName$
  .map(currentClassName => 
    div([
      button(
        '#button' + currentClassName, ['Click me']
      )
    ]));
...
```

[Working demo](https://jsbin.com/radepuyoye/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer. The thing I don't understand is that why I must use delay(0). I mean there is one click event and when it's happend, the element has foo class. How does stream which subcribes the click events of bar also wor? Could you please explain how does using delay fix the problem? About using toggleDriver, I think you are right. It's better to use v-dom instead of $. I created the toggle driver because i thought changing class of element was a side effect and doing it in a driver was more easier than writing the same code everywhere I use virtual-dom. Thanx for help again

Comment: Glad to help you. However I'm sorry but I can't explain. I can only guess that it might be an issue with the way events are handled by the dom driver : all events bubble up to the root element and form one stream. Then doing .select returns a copy of this stream filtered by target. Intuitively I thought that letting for the dom to re-render (delay(0)) may help. I think it may be good to report it as an issue on GitHub. (written on my phone)

Comment: About changing the classNames, you are right, this is a side effect. But it's already handled by the domDriver when you change the virtual tree. Think the vTree as the graphical representation of your app at time _x_.